# SKShapeNode .strokeColor to look same as .fillColor when change node.alpha

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

When I change SKShapeNode's `.alpha`, its `stroke` shows itself as if `.strokeColor` of node was brighter than its `.fillColor`. Setting `.lineWidth` to 0 canceles antialiased smotheness that the stroke provides. Same does setting `.strokeColor` to `SKColor.clearColor`.

[image: SKShapeNode stroke alpha issue]

**Question**

What is the best way to make stroke look the same as fill when changing `node.alpha`, preserving the antialiased smootheness of edges?

Comment: have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26640893/4078517

Comment: @Darvydas thank you, this worked. The idea is to get HSBA of `.strokeColor` like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071756/is-there-function-to-convert-uicolor-to-hue-saturation-brightness then change alpha to desired

Comment: I just posted a link, not an answer :). You can post answer and mark it :)

Comment: @Darvydas I have encountered another problem on this way. As the node's fill covers node's stroke, stroke's alpha must be set to 0 so that it actually wouldn't be seen. But this canceles antialiasing. So actually it does not work. I guess the only way is to convert SKShapeNode to SKSpriteNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is possible to set `alpha` of node's `stroke` directly by getting its' colors' `HSBA` and reassigning a new color with different `alpha` to the `stroke` (for more info look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071756/is-there-function-to-convert-uicolor-to-hue-saturation-brightness)), as the node's `fill` covers node's `stroke`, `stroke's` `alpha` must be set to `0` so that it actually wouldn't be seen. But this canceles antialiasing.

So it appears, that the only way to achieve smooth node's edges with no `stroke` be seen, is to convert `SKShapeNode` to `SKSpriteNode` and reset `sprite.alpha` to desired.

[image: smooth]

Here is a code snippet in Swift

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: self.view!.textureFromNode(shapeNode))
```

Its' not that bad, because, according to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/textureFromNode:)

> The node being rendered does not need to appear in the view’s
>   presented scene.

However, you still have to have access to the `view` from where the conversion takes place.